# eventListener to buttons created from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, addeventlistener

I am having trouble with creating an eventListener for buttons.
Please check my code and help if you can:
https://jsbin.com/lavaruk/edit?html,js,output 
   `document.getElementByTagName('button').addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });`
Thanks.
Peter

Comment: `document.getElementByTagName` does what? Please follow the documentation ...

Comment: Please add your code here and create a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: <var mgk = ["607","608","609","610","612","613","615"];

function mentokMgk(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < mgk.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('button');
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list;
}

document.getElementById('mentok-mgk').appendChild(mentokMgk(mgk));
document.getElementByTagName('button').addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });>

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByTagName` and you need to iterate the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
var mgk = ["607","608","609","610","612","613","615"];

function mentokMgk(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < mgk.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('button');
      item.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert('click');
});
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    return list;
}

document.getElementById('mentok-mgk').appendChild(mentokMgk(mgk));
```

After create your var item, define an EventListener for this item.

Comment: One more question: what's the index for the current button element? Like I want to write in the alert box the number if I click the button (e.g. 607).